# Parse Mongo update JSON string to DBObject

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am trying to construct `Mongo Query` at runtime, so parsing `JSON string` to `DBObject`.

I have tried as below:

```
String then = "{$set : {"JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$" : "Waltham", "JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$" : "MA", "JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$" : "Middlesex", "JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$" : "USA", "JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$" : "02451", "JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$" : "42.398708",  "JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$" : "-71.259216", "JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$" : "71650: Metropolitan NECTA |715: Combined NECTA", "JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$" : "71654: NECTA Division", "JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$" : "DV257165|MT257165", "JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$" : "781"}}"

DBObject thenQuery = (DBObject) JSON.parse(then);
```

Result :

```
{ "$set" : { "JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$" : "781"}}
```

Can anyone sort me were I am going wrong else suggest way to work it out?

Comment: Thanks @Shrabanee .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same property name multiple times inside the object, that's why you are getting the output.

> `Property name` should be unique inside an object.

You should not use `"JobDoc.DataElementsRollup.ConsolidatedONET.#text.$"` multiple times in your query.